# Find List obj with Dictionary Key?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a reference to a number of objects stored in a List and Dictionary. Is there a method to find and change values of an object in a list by providing a key value from the dictionary?

```
public bool isChanged(List<obj> original, List<obj> recent)
{
  bool isChanged = false;

  Dictionary<long, obj> originalPK = new Dictionary<long, obj>();
  Dictionary<long, obj> recentPK = new Dictionary<long, obj>();
  Dictionary<long, obj> deletedentries = new Dictionary<long, obj>();
  Dictionary<long, obj> newentries = new Dictionary<long, obj>();

  // used foreach to copy obj ref in original into originalPK
  // used foreach to copy obj ref in recent into recentPK
  // placed refs to identical objs within originalPK and recentPK into existinboth
  // placed refs from within originalPK that weren't in recentPK into deletedentries
}
```

Instead of removing refs to objs in original using the key-value from deletedentries, I want to search through original with the key/value of deletedentries and then change a property on original. Something like this:

```
foreach(long key in deletedentries.Keys)
{
  original[key].isActive = "false";
}
```

Comment: There certainly is a way, but you will have to add some code so we can work from there.

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: If the values in `deleted` are references to the objects in `original`, then modifying the value in `deleted[key]` is the same as modifying the original object.